# Profile types with unique fields (Profile2?)

Tags: users

I'm trying to achieve the following with Drupal 7:

- Admin user will create all user accounts, users can not
- Admin has a choice of two profile types (Coach, Player)
- Coach and Player's user registration forms will have different required fields

I've been able to successfully setup the Profile2 module, and create two profile types. However, when I add fields to the Coach's profile those fields also show up in the Player profile when I go to /admin/people (add-user player-profile button)

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, or perhaps I have something configured incorrectly with Profile2?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The profile 2 page states:

> Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be
>   assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer
>   profile)

Did you set-up different roles for coach and player?

Comment: I did indeed - perhaps that's the step I'm missing? Assigning the correct permissions to the roles?

Comment: In admin/people/permissions I don't see the ability to configure something along the lines of "If I'm creating a Player profile, only show me the Player profile fields". Perhaps I'm not thinking about this correctly?